# Passport not persisting authentication with Node.js backend and React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am utilizing a Node.js and express backend with a React frontend. Currently, I am using **Passport.js** with their **Local Authentication Strategy**. Whenever I log in on my React login component, it works fine in the Node.js app.post("/login") callback. However, whenever I go to a different page using react router, or I simply refresh, I print out req.user in my react frontend which returns undefined.

### Backend

Below, if you go to app.post("/login"), you'll see I print out req.user and req.isAuthenticated(). Req.user returns the user object, and req.isAuthenticated() returns true. However, whenever I refresh or go to another link using react-router, my frontend returns that req.user is undefined when it gets the information from the backend from the app.get("/get-user") route.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const session = require("express-session");

const app = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://tacobellcommercial:"+process.env.PASSWORD+"@cluster0.gh4uyob.mongodb.net/")

app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors({
    origin: "*"
}))

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(passport.authenticate("session"));

/* PASSPORT LOCAL STRATEGY */
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function verify(username, password, callback){
    User.find({username: username}).then(array=>{
        if (array.length === 0){
            console.log("IN HERE")
            return callback(null, false, {message: "Incorrect username or password..."})
        }else{
            bcrypt.compare(password, array[0].password).then((result)=>{
                if (result){
                    console.log("YES")
                    return callback(null, array[0], {message: "Successfully logged in..."})
                }else{
                    console.log("NOPE");
                    return callback(null, false, {message: "Incorrect username or password"})
                }
            })
        }

    })
}))

passport.serializeUser((user, callback)=>{
    callback(null, user.username);
})

passport.deserializeUser((username, callback)=>{
    User.find({username: username}).then(user=>{
        console.log(user[0]);
        callback(err, user[0]);
    })
})


/* MONGOOSE */

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
})

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

/*ROUTES*/

app.post("/login", (req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate("local", (error, user, message)=>{
        console.log("called");
        if (error){
            console.log(error);
            console.log("in error");
            res.json({message: error});
        }else if (!user){
            console.log("in no user");
            res.json({message: "No user exists..."});
        }else{
            console.log("User found and password matches...")
            req.login(user, (err)=>{
                if (err){
                    res.json({message: "Failed to login"})
                }else{
                    console.log("Logged in successfully...")
                    res.json({message: "Success"})
                    console.log("Logged in " + req.isAuthenticated());
                    console.log(req.user);
                }
            })
        }
    })(req, res, next);
})

app.post("/register", (req, res)=>{
    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}).then((object)=>{
        if (object){
            console.log(object)
            console.log(req.body);
            res.json({message:"User exists"});
        }else{
            console.log("hi");
            const newUser = new User({
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password
            })
            newUser.save().then(userObject=>{
                console.log("Saved user object");
                res.json({message: "Success"})
            })
        }
    })
})

app.get("/user", (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.user);
    res.send({message: req.user});
})


/**/


app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server started");
})
```

### **Frontend**

**Login Component**

```
import React from "react";
import UserContext from "../Context";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
 
function Login(){

    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState("")
    const [password, setPassword ] = React.useState("")
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = React.useState(false);

    const {login} = React.useContext(UserContext)
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/user", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(res=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, [])

    return(
        <form className="login" onSubmit={(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            
            const result = login(username, password);
            result.then(data=>{
                if (data.message === "Success"){
                    setRedirect(true);
                }
            })
        }}>
            {redirect ? <Navigate to="/"/> : null}
            <h1>Username</h1>
            <input placeholder="Username" onChange={(event)=>{
                setUsername(event.target.value);
            }}/>
            <h1>Password</h1>
            <input placeholder="Password" onChange={(event)=>{
                setPassword(event.target.value);
            }}/>

            <button type="submit">Make account</button>
        </form>  
    )
}

export default Login;
```

**Context**

```
import React from "react";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function UserContextProvider({children}){

    function register(username, password){
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: username,
                password: password
            }
        }).then(res=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then(data=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
    }

    function login(username, password){
        const data = fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
        }).then(res=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })

        return data;
    }

    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={{register, login}}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
    )
}


export default UserContext;
```

**App.jsx** (this is where I console.log(data) where it's supposed to be req.user and it returns undefined in React.useEffect!)

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Routes, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import {UserContextProvider} from "./Context";

function App(){
    
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/user", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(res=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
        })
    }, [])

    return(
        <UserContextProvider>
            <div className="header">
                <div className="navbar">
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
                </div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </div>
            
        </UserContextProvider>
    )
}

export default App;
```

I've researched this for around 7 hours straight and I can't find out what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you try replacing `*` in cors to the url of your react frontend.

Comment: Put it to origin: "http://localhost:3001/" but does not work regardless, it fails to fetch with an error saying it was blocked by the cors policy.

Comment: can you instead try to serve your react frontent on local ip, eg."http://192.168.1.20:3000" something. What you are using to bundle react

Comment: I tried what you said, I bundled react using my local IP on my network and set the same IP to the list of allowed origins in the cors modification. It still does not work and returns undefined when trying to print req.user

Comment: Try to do the same for the server, change  `fetch("http://localhost:3000/user")` to `fetch("http://192.168.1.20:3000/user")` something in your react code, depending upon your local-ip.

Comment: Did exactly what you said, changed it to my local ip on port 3000 because that's what node was running on. Still prints out undefined everytime I print it on the useEffect hook in the App.jsx file. I also made sure all the other fetch requests were changed to the correct IP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in `fetch` request that your are making.
You just need to add `credentials:"include"` option in `fetch` , in order for the browser to send credentials (cookies,auth etc.) with the request.

Do this for all the requests,

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/user", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials:"include"
    })
```

I think you also need to set the `credentials:true` in `cors` in your backend.

Comment: Does not work, tested with both local ip and localhost in the address; still returns undefined. Added credentials in all post and get requests, added credentials: true in the cors configuration, and set the origin "http://localhost:3001" to be allowed in the cors origin configuration as react was running on port 3000.

Comment: @Chris Why are you using `localhost`(remove completely), please only use local ip address ("192.168.1.20" something) for now. Also in `desrializeUser` function, is it logging the correct user information?

Comment: Yes, it is logging the correct user information